# interactive shell script: recursion too deep

Tags: shell, recursion

I have written an interactive shell script in KSH, there is a main menu where the options call different functions stored as code snippets on separate files.

The script works fine but after a while the script exits with 'recursion too deep'

There is no obvious pattern of when it happens, it can happen using any of the functions at any time. The only clear pattern is that the longer I use the script the more likely it is to cause the error.

There are no recursive functions in the script, so I assume that I am creating a callback loop somewhere that gets too big after a while.

Is there a function I can call that will clear any code queue that has built up? ( I'm new to shell scripting - I am remembering the clearQueue function in jquery animations )

I've tried to find the callback loop with no success so a workaround is tempting

thanks

Comment: Once the functions handling whatever task you want is done, what happens then, is the "menu" function called again? Then you have an indirect recursion of the "menu" function, and sooner or later it will go to deep. Try using a loop to display the menu instead.

Comment: Yes, at the end of each task function it calls the menu function. I'm afraid I don't understand why this causes a build up of recursions... and I'm not sure what you mean by using a loop to call the menu instead of a call back... how would that look?   For info my menu consists of echoing the menu list, having an input set the selection variable and then a bunch of what ifs for the action.  Do all the what ifs end up stacking if this is all repeatedly called?

Comment: Then just changes that so the task function silently exits, and goes *back* to the menu function, which then loops to display the menu and ask for selection again.

Comment: I think I know what you mean - I'll give it a go

Comment: Actually I don't get it.  Can you explain why calling the menu from a loop has a different impact than calling it from the end of a task function?

Comment: Not *calling* the menu function, just let it iterate... I'll write an answer to show the principle.

Comment: It looks like you have been pointed in the right direction. But in the future, please don't rely on verbal descriptions of  your problem. We're here to help you **fix your code**. Mind you, *not **all** of your code ;-)*, just a [Minimal,Complete,Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  . That description is very general and IMHO opaque to a newbie, so just remember that a good question will have a small set of sample data (or behavior), expected output (or evidence of action), curent code/output/error msgs and your thoughts about why things aren't working. . Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the recursion error was because I was sourcing files too many times and exceeding the file operator limit

I rewrote it so I only had to source files once and it was fine

Answer (score 1):

In pseudo-code you could do something like

```
while true; do
    print_menu
    val=get_input
    case $val in
        1)
            do_task_1
            ;;
        ; etc...
    end
done
```

Once `do_task_1` is done, the function or script or whatever it is returns, and the `case` statement ends, and the loop iterates printing the menu and getting the input again.

Comment: Thanks, there is quite a bit in there I'm not familiar with - I'm restricted at work to an old Korn Shell that doesn't even allow any bash, but you've pointed me in the right direction. I've found the select loop in ksh I'll apply this too.